# Azure Data Factory - Error: The specified resource does not exist

Tags: azure, powershell, oracle-adf

I m trying to run custom activity in Azure data factory which executes PowerShell script that will change the blobs tier to "hot". I created Batch account and I have saved the script on the storage account. Both Batch account and storage account successfully connect to custom activity.  When I trigger the ADF pipeline I got the following error:

[image]

Error in the output file of Batch account:
`<Error> <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code> <Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:e5313310-001e-000b-269b-bd9c33000000 Time:2023-07-23T19:25:38.5391510Z</Message> </Error>`

I tried to changed the access level of container from private to blob but it didn't help.

Any suggestion please what could solve the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with azure batch, not adf. Have you tried running azure batch directly. Keep in mind that there are two other "serverless" platforms that may be better suited. Azure Functions and Azure Automation

Comment: This is not a normal Azure Error.  Usually with Azure you are making an HTTP Request and getting back in the Response a status code like 200 OK.  The error you are getting is a Window Exit Code.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-not-found?tabs=bicep

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you are getting is because you are not enabling public access for the storage account to provide anonymous users read access to a container and its blobs (**The container where the batch account is storing the output files**).

[image]

After this you will be able to access the links given by output in Azure Data Factory.

> {"errorCategory":0,"code":"FailureExitCode","message":"The task exited with an exit code representing a failure","details":[{"Name":"Message","Value":"The task process exited with an unexpected exit code"},{"Name":"AdditionalErrorCode","Value":"FailureExitCode"}]}

Regarding above error make sure you are using **appropriate operating system in batch pool** and all the linked services and storage accounts are connected properly.

[image]

Here my Data factory Custom activity settings:

[image]

**My PowerShell file sample included all required modules to be installed:**

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201  -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
Set-AzContext -Subscription "subscription Id"
$ctx  =  (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "resource group"  -Name "storage acc name").Context
$blob  = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "container name"  -Blob "blob name"  -Context $ctx
$blob.BlobClient.SetAccessTier("tire",  $null,  "Standard")
```

**Its completed Succesfully:**

[image]